# vba fastest way compare two lists of numbers

Tags: arrays, vba, dictionary, comparison, ms-access-2010

I am working in an MS-Access 2010 environment. I have two strings of numbers. I need to compare them and find the missing numbers in list 2. These lists can be very large (more than 100.000 numbers), so I need a fast method to compare them.

Let us say the lists are as follows:

L1: "1,2,4,5,6,8,9"

L2: "1,2,6,9"

So I need to find the numbers 4, 5 and 8. How can I do this most efficiently? I can put them in an array and them loop through both arrays, but I am afraid it will be very slow if both lists contain over 100.000 values.

Would a dictionary approach be more efficient? If so, how?

Comment: Can there be repeats? Are the numbers guaranteed to be capped (smaller than some number)?

Comment: There are no repeats, the numbers can be up to 1.000.000 max.

Comment: In which form do you have the "lists you are talking about"? Can you easily place them in two 1D arrays? But not by iteration...

Comment: Are the lists in tables?  `SELECT L1 FROM Table1 LEFT JOIN Table2 ON Table1.L1 = Table2.L2 WHERE ISNULL(L2)`

Comment: No, the lists are in a string, not a table.

Comment: Creating an array is easy enough: MyArray = Split(MyString,",")., But then, how to compare both arrays without looping through all the rows multiple times? That is why I was thinking of a dictionary approach

Comment: I didn't observe that ms-Access is tagged... I was thinking at Excel. It has 'Match` function able to really match two arrays. Anyhow, I will prepare an answer using a dictionary and two arrays.

Comment: Will the numbers in the two strings always be sorted in ascending order like the example?

Comment: Please, test the code I provided and send some feedback. Mainly, how much time does it take...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please, try the next code. It uses a dictionary and the two strings split in arrays. It needs only two iterations per each array, which should not take too much. The arrays content not necessary to be sorted. It returns in a third array, its content being Joined and returned in `Immediate Window`. Of course, it can be used as an array, depending on your need:

```
Sub testCompare1DArrays()
  Dim arr1, arr2, noMatch, i As Long, k As Long, dict2 As Object
  
    arr1 = Split("1,2,4,5,6,8,9", ",")
    arr2 = Split("1,2,6,9", ",")
    Set dict2 = CreateObject("scripting.dictionary")
    
    'place the array to be checked in the dictionary (as keys)
    For i = 0 To UBound(arr2)
        dict2(arr2(i)) = vbNullString
    Next i
    
    ReDim noMatch(UBound(arr1)) 'set the array to keep the processed result to surelly have space for all occurrences
    For i = 1 To UBound(arr1)
        If Not dict2.exists(arr1(i)) Then noMatch(k) = arr1(i): k = k + 1 'buld the returned arry for elements not being found as keys
    Next i
    
    If k > 0 Then
        ReDim Preserve noMatch(k - 1) 'keep only loaded elements
        Debug.Print Join(noMatch, "|") 'return in Immediate Window (Ctrl + G)
    Else
        Debug.Print "All elements of arr2 exists in arr1..."
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: It works, and extremely fast. I tried with 100.000 values on both lists and performance was less than one second! Wonderfull. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

An alternative method to achieve this desired result is to utilize the collections object.

First, loop through the second list adding each  number to a collection and using each number as its own item key.

Second, loop through the first list testing each number against the second list's keys.

If the key does not exist, add the number to a collection of missing keys.

```
Private Sub compareLists()
  Dim list1 As Variant, list2 As Variant
  Dim testNumbers As New Collection, _ 
    missingNumbers As New Collection
  Dim i As Long
  Dim number As String
  list1 = Split("1,2,4,5,6,8,9", ",")
  list2 = Split("1,2,6,9", ",")
 
  'Prepare numbers from list2
  For i = 0 to UBound(list2)
      number = list2(i)
      testNumbers.Add number, number
  Next i

  'Identify numbers in list1 missing from list2
  For i = 0 to UBound(list1)
    number = list1(i)
    On Error Resume Next
    testNumbers.Item number
    If Err.Number = 5 And Err.Number <> 457 Then _
      missingNumbers.Add number, number
  Next i

End Sub
```

Perhaps a faster solution exists, but I tend to prefer utilizing collections.